# Cannot read property '1' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, html

I've checked some questions very similar to mine and tried everything I knew. This bug is driving me crazy.

I am doing a "game" which consists on a NxN tables with numbers 1-8 and the number 0 (this numbers are represented as image files, and the number 0 is a transparent image). The purpouse of the game is to get all numbers in order. This is a link so you get a brief idea of what I am talking about --> [Game](http://gyazo.com/8dd48815b3e939754ca1c2f73976a20e).

So when I click number 2 (In the example) It should go down and the transparent image should go up (changing the src).

This is my code:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
const N=3;
var aTabla= CrearTabla(N);

document.write("<table>");
for (f=0;f<N;f++){
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (c=0;c<N;c++){
        document.write("<td>");
        document.write('<img src = "Numbers2/n'+aTabla[f][c]+'.gif" id="im'+f+c+'" onclick="mover('+f+','+c+');tiempo()" >');
        document.write("</td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");


function mover(f,c){

    //Derecha
    if(aTabla[f][c+1] == 0){

        aAux = aTabla[f][c+1];
        aTabla[f][c+1] = aTabla[f][c];
        aTabla[f][c] = aAux;

        aux = document.images["im"+f+(c+1)].src;
        document.images["im"+f+(c+1)].src = document.images["im"+f+c].src;
        document.images["im"+f+c].src = aux;
    }//Izquierda
    if(aTabla[f][c-1] == 0){

        aAux = aTabla[f][c-1];
        aTabla[f][c-1] = aTabla[f][c];
        aTabla[f][c] = aAux;

        aux = document.images["im"+f+(c-1)].src;
        document.images["im"+f+(c-1)].src = document.images["im"+f+c].src;
        document.images["im"+f+c].src = aux;
    }
    //Arriba
    if(aTabla[f-1][c] == 0 && aTabla[f-1][c] != 'undefined'){

        aAux = aTabla[f-1][c];
        aTabla[f-1][c] = aTabla[f][c];
        aTabla[f][c] = aAux;

        aux = document.images["im"+(f-1)+c].src;
        document.images["im"+(f-1)+c].src = document.images["im"+f+c].src;
        document.images["im"+f+c].src = aux;
    }
    //Abajo 
    if(aTabla[f+1][c] == 0 && aTabla[f+1][c] != 'undefined'){

        aAux = aTabla[f+1][c];
        aTabla[f+1][c] = aTabla[f][c];
        aTabla[f][c] = aAux;

        aux = document.images["im"+(f+1)+c].src;
        document.images["im"+(f+1)+c].src = document.images["im"+f+c].src;
        document.images["im"+f+c].src = aux;
    }



}
```

function CrearTabla(N) is an already done function that works perfecty. It return a 2D array. And the parameter is use as NxN so in my case it creates a 3x3 table.

The games works perfectly when I move numbers left, right and up, even when I move numbers down if the case that they are in line 2 and 3 ( f == 0 and f == 1 in array positions). But when I try to move and element that is on the first line (number 2 in my the link that i provided) It gives an error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined**

What can I do to fix that? I am new to javascript.

Comment: When you debug this, which specific line throws the error?  What are the values of the variables on that line?  Where did those values come from?

Comment: //Arriba
if(aTabla[f-1][c] == 0 && aTabla[f-1][c] != 'undefined') and this //Arriba
if(aTabla[f-1][c] == 0 && aTabla[f-1][c] != 'undefined')

Comment: Then either `aTable` is undefined or `aTable[f-1]` is undefined.  Which one is it?  And where did you expect it to be defined?  You need to debug this.

Comment: Yeah `aTable[f-1]`is undefined thats why I put `!= 'undefined`Dunno how to debug it :S

Comment: No, you put `aTabla[f-1][c] != 'undefined'`.  If `aTabla[f-1]` is undefined then you can't reference the `c` property on it.  Undefined doesn't have properties you can reference.

Comment: I know what you mean but `aTabla[f][c-1]` is not defined too and it doesnt cause problems.

Comment: I don't think you *do* know what I mean.  You're not trying to reference any properties on `aTabla[f][c-1]`, so of course it's not going to fail.  But you *are* trying to reference properties on `aTabla[f-1]`, which according to you is undefined.  You can't reference properties on `undefined`.  That's exactly what the error is telling you.  Just because you can reference properties on other things doesn't change the fact that you can't reference properties on `undefined`.

Comment: If `aTabla[f-1]` is undefined then you are trying to do `undefined[c]` which will cause the error. Also, that is *not* how you check for undefined. Either of `x !== undefined` or `typeof(x) !== 'undefined'` works, but not that.

Comment: So what do you suggest to make this "game" work. Maybe I'm approaching it wrong, I am quite stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to check that you are always accessing a valid location, that is both the row and the column is between 0 and 2. In your function we can assume that (f, c) is a valid location in the board. But things like (f-1, c) might not always be a valid location. So, you need to check them:

```
if(c+1 <= 2 && aTabla[f][c+1] == 0){...
if(c-1 >= 0 && aTabla[f][c-1] == 0){...
if(f-1 >= 0 && aTabla[f-1][c] == 0){...
if(f+1 <= 2 && aTabla[f+1][c] == 0){...
```

If the first condition is false, [the second condition will not be evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), preventing the TypeError in your current code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't see it :S